# Failed to fetch Ubuntu 11.04 repos

Tags: 11.04, server, apt, updates, repository

I'm running 11.04 server, and I'm getting errors updating default repos when I run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

The repos that return a 404 error are default Ubuntu Natty repos like http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/source/.

I can't update my installation since these repos keep failing. Is my only choice to reinstall my distro?

Comment: Well, 11.04 is beyond end of life, so yes you will need to upgrade as you will not longer be receiving updates or security patches.

Comment: Since I need update-manager-d to upgrade, will I need to change my repos from archive.ubuntu.com to old-releases.ubuntu.com, install update-manager-d, and move on to 12.04?

Comment: Well, That may work.

Comment: You can not skip releases, so you would have to update to 11.10 then 12.04. It may be easier and faster to back up your configuration and data and perform a fresh install.